# conflict of jQuery Slider with prettyPhoto

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i have a problem in my script which is conflicting . jQuery Slider and prettyPhoto is not working together how i can solve this problem kindly anybody help me  i already upload the page we shows that pretty photo is working but slider is not working please any body watch its source code and tell me the solution i shall be very thankful to you. this is very important project for me

link is http://www.bizedge.co/homesoccer.html#

Answer (score 0):

After linking to your script - Follow it with this. This has solved many jQuery conflicts for me.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
 </script>
```

[Also here is a great article on jQuery conflicts.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

You are including two version of jQuery, really not recommended usually, but only for special cases, the versions are:

- jquery-1.4.1.min.js
- jquery-1.3.2.min.js

You have to link only one, possibly the newest (1.10.2), ore you'll face conflict issues.

If you are dependent on ancient jQuery versions api consider to refactor you code to use only one version of jQuery and save time and pain.

Eventually, but I don't think you need it, you can handle multiple versions of jQuery using [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of
>   $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores
>   them.
>
> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not
>   recommended), calling $.noConflict(true) from the second version will
>   return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first
>   version.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/